# different Menu position showing same menu

Tags: menus

Weird Problem:
I registered two menus (theme-positions) and then added two different menus to each (in Wordpress Admin), but it always shows same menu in both positions:

sidebar.php

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( 

    array( 
        'menu_name' => 'Header Menu',
        'theme-location' => 'header-menu',
    )

);

?>

<div id="menu-content" class="back-canvas">
    <div class="inner-menu-content">
</div>

</div>

<?php

wp_nav_menu( 

    array( 

        'menu_name' => 'Footer Menu',

        'theme-location' => 'footer-menu'

    )

);

?>
```

functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'bc_init' );
function bc_init() {
add_editor_style( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/editor-style.css'    );
    load_theme_textdomain( 'bc_leimcke', get_template_directory() . '/lang' );
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'header-menu' => 'Header Menu',
        'footer-menu' => 'Footer Menu'
) );
 }
```

**has anyone had the same problem? any hints?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a syntax error:

replace `'theme-location'` by `'theme_location'`.

Always think about underscores in Wordpress variables/functions names ;)

wp_nav_menu() : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: unbeliveable i didn't see that! Thank YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Dashboard > Appearance > Menus`, then under your menu links you see `Menu Settings`.

Check if position of each menu is checked as you want.

Comment: Yes, in the Admin-Panel everything is as i want it. I've even looked at the database, and themes_options in wp_options table has different values in the JSON-Like option_value. I realy can't imagine why Wordpress is giving me two exactly same menus