# Custom menu is rendered in all menus

Tags: menus

I am currently working on my own theme. In this theme I want two menus `topmenu` and `bottommenu`.

In the functions.php file I have the following code:

```
// This adds the support to add a thumbnail and custom menus
function thumbnail_menu_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'topmenu' => __( 'Top menu' ),
            'bottommenu' => __( 'Bottom menu' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'thumbnail_menu_support' );
```

In my header.php and in the footer.php I have the following code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'              => 'Top menu',
    'menu_id'           => 'topmenu',
    'container'         => false,
    'fallback_cb'       => false,
    'theme-location'    => 'topmenu'
) ); ?>
```

and

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'              => 'Bottom menu',
    'menu_id'           => 'bottommenu',
    'container'         => false,
    'fallback_cb'       => false,
    'theme-location'    => 'bottommenu'
) );
```

Now, when I make a menu in the backend of Wordpress, and specify that it should only be in the top menu, it will be rendered in both menus.

See this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer on stackexchange as well: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184149/132736

I need to replace the `'theme-location'` by `'theme_location'`. I simply misread the function reference on the WordPress codex.